# Помогите не могу разобраться в чем проблема

Tags: python, aiogram

```
from aiogram import types, utils, executor, Dispatcher, Bot
from telegram_bot_calendar import DetailedTelegramCalendar, LSTEP


bot = Bot(token='мой токен')
dp = Dispatcher(bot)

@dp.message_handler(commands=['start'])
async def echo(message: types.Message):

    calendar, step = DetailedTelegramCalendar().build()
    await message.answer(message.chat.id, 'SELECT {LSTEP[step]}', LSTEP[step],  reply_markup=step)


@dp.callback_query_handler(DetailedTelegramCalendar.func())
async def inline_kb_answer_callback_handler (query):
    result, key, step = DetailedTelegramCalendar().process(query.data)

    if not result and key:
        await query.edit_message_text(f"Select  {LSTEP[step]}",
                                    query.message.chat.id,
                                    query.message.message_id,
                                    reply_markup=key)
    elif result:
        await query.edit_message_text(f"You selected  {result}",
                                    query.message.chat.id,
                                    query.messagemessage.message_id)

executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)
```

Ошибка:

```
Updates were skipped successfully.
Task exception was never retrieved
future: <Task finished name='Task-9' coro=<Dispatcher._process_polling_updates() done, defined at C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\python_basic_diploma\venv\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\dispatcher.py:407> exception=BadRequest('Unsupported parse_mode')>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\python_basic_diploma\venv\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\dispatcher.py", line 415, in _process_polling_updates
    for responses in itertools.chain.from_iterable(await self.process_updates(updates, fast)):
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\python_basic_diploma\venv\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\dispatcher.py", line 235, in process_updates
    return await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\python_basic_diploma\venv\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\handler.py", line 116, in notify
    response = await handler_obj.handler(*args, **partial_data)
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\python_basic_diploma\venv\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\dispatcher.py", line 256, in process_update
    return await self.message_handlers.notify(update.message)
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\python_basic_diploma\venv\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\handler.py", line 116, in notify
    response = await handler_obj.handler(*args, **partial_data)
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\python_basic_diploma\tests.py", line 12, in echo
    await message.answer(message.chat.id, 'SELECT {LSTEP[step]}', LSTEP[step],  reply_markup=step)
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\python_basic_diploma\venv\lib\site-packages\aiogram\types\message.py", line 397, in answer
    return await self.bot.send_message(
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\python_basic_diploma\venv\lib\site-packages\aiogram\bot\bot.py", line 341, in send_message
    result = await self.request(api.Methods.SEND_MESSAGE, payload)
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\python_basic_diploma\venv\lib\site-packages\aiogram\bot\base.py", line 236, in request
    return await api.make_request(await self.get_session(), self.server, self.__token, method, data, files,
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\python_basic_diploma\venv\lib\site-packages\aiogram\bot\api.py", line 140, in make_request
    return check_result(method, response.content_type, response.status, await response.text())
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\python_basic_diploma\venv\lib\site-packages\aiogram\bot\api.py", line 115, in check_result
    exceptions.BadRequest.detect(description)
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\python_basic_diploma\venv\lib\site-packages\aiogram\utils\exceptions.py", line 141, in detect
    raise cls(description)
aiogram.utils.exceptions.BadRequest: Unsupported parse_mode
```

Comment: Приведите полный текст ошибки

Comment: А вообще в строке `await message.answer` вы написали неправильно абсолютно всё. Согласно [документации](https://docs.aiogram.dev/en/latest/telegram/types/message.html#aiogram.types.message.Message.answer), первый аргумент text должен быть строкой, а вы пихаете число. Второй аргумент parse_mode должен быть `"HTML"` или `"Markdown"` или `None`, а вы туда запихали какой-то неведомый `'SELECT {LSTEP[step]}'`

Comment: Согласен с замечанием от @anderymal, попробуйте явно указать параметры которые передаете.